# XSLT - How to count nodes conditionally?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I've been wrapping my head around this and I'm pretty sure there's got to be a basic solution.

I'm trying to convert an xml file to XHTML using XSLT 1.0, and I want to have a section where, for every player (fD:jogador in the XML file), the code will look at their @id attribute, then check the goals element and its goal sub-elements (fD:golos and fD:golo), and count all the goals that were scored by the player with @id equal to the player we're processing.

What I have now, is in the template matching the player,

```
<xsl:call-template name="calcgolos">
    <xsl:with-param name="id" select="@id"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

The template itself looks like this:

```
 <xsl:template name="calcgolos">
    <xsl:param name="id"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(//fD:golo/@marcador = $id)"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

This is just returning 0 every time, which isn't exactly what I'm looking for!

When I tried inputting this expression in eclipse's XPath processor, with the $id replaced by an actual id, in this case, "POR_NANI", it... exploded. If I do it without the count, though, the correct elements show up, so the syntax can't be *too* wrong.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Can you try `count(//fD:golo[@marcador = $id])"`?

Comment: Please, edit the question and provide a complete, but not big source XML document. Without this it isn't possible to say if a specific XPath expression really selects the wanted nodes, or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count the nodes, not the test.  Try this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(//fD:golo[@marcador = $id])"/>
```

Comment: It spits out:
17:58:09,920 ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Syntax error in 'count(//fD:golo/[@marcador = $id])'.

It *DOES* work in Eclipse's xpath, so now the problem is probably with the $id...

Comment: Nevermind, it worked now! Thanks a bunch, I knew it was something obvious escaping me :)